# SSRS Server Error Application

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Sometimes I receive the following error, when I try to open reports on browser. More interestingly, this problem is solved by itself and occurs from time to time. What is the reason for that? I've read some other posts, users there restart the service to solve the issue. But how can I prevent this error?

[image]

One more question: I'm developing Reports on Visual Studio 2008, how can I find Report Server name, so that to restart it?

Comment: That error message is the generic error message used to hide the details of your code from the public.  If you can open a browser on the server that is hosting your ssrs instance, or if you follow the instructions in the error message and update the web.config file you will see details on what caused the error instead of this generic error message.

Comment: @JessePotter, how can I find where my ssrs is being hosted? And how can I reach web.config?))

Comment: Open cmd.exe.  Ping the url.  I am able to see the name of the server in the response.

Comment: The web.config file will be in different default locations depending on your version of SQL.  Here is a link to those default locations: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh389762.aspx

Comment: @JessePotter, it didn't help. I've a directory structure similar to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\(80,90,100,110)/ Isn't it possible to learn it from Visual Studio where I develop a reports?

Comment: Not sure how you have SSRS setup, but it sounds like SSRS is hosted on a production machine.  My setup has SSRS hosted on a production server and I have Visual Studio on my machine.  I can develop SSRS reports in Visual Studio, but when I deploy them I right-click on the rdl file in Visual Studio and select Deploy.  This opens a connection to the SSRS web API hosted on the production server and pushes the rdl into production.

If this sounds like your setup then you need to login to the server hosting SSRS and find the web.config on that machine.

Comment: @JessePotter, I do exatly as you do. Deployment works the same way. So how can I find that machine where SSRS is hosted))

Comment: right click on your SSRS project in Visual Studio and select Properties.  You should see your report server url in the TargetServerURL in the list of properties.  It should look something like this http://domain.com/reportserver.  Open up a command prompt and ping the domain like this: ping domain.com.  When I do this my server responds with an IP address.  If RDP is setup on the SSRS server you can use RDP and provide this IP to access the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the log file on Report Server to analyze what is the root issue.